притяжательные местоимения
Притяжательные местоимения его, ее, их не изменяются по падежам. Но имеют род и число.
Так вот, в чем заключается мой вопрос.  Личные местоимениях 3 лица единственного числа изменяются по родам, то есть она, оно это формы местоимения он. Относится ли это правило к притяжательным местоимениям? Ее это будет форма притяжательного местоимения он?

Да, вы правы. Притяжательные местоимения в русском языке тоже изменяются по родам и числам. И "её" это форма притяжательного местоимения от "она" и, соответственно, от "он". Но вы не расслабляйтесь. Сейчас вам другой пользователь принесёт четыре огромных ответа от "сервиса нейросеть".

@Третий глаз
Я вообще-то в отпуске, если вы обо мне.  Хочу лично от вас отдохнуть. Но вы можете посмеяться над собой. // Ваш ответ:  "Да, вы правы. Притяжательные местоимения в русском языке тоже изменяются по родам и числам. И "её" это форма притяжательного местоимения от "она" и, соответственно, от "он". Но вы не расслабляйтесь. Сейчас вам другой пользователь принесёт четыре огромных ответа от "сервиса нейросеть", почитаем, посмеёмся.//Вот это действительно смешно. Если будут правильные ответы, посмеемся все.

@Sharon, это камушек в наш огород, наверное. Что смешного — непонятно. Но нейросеть намного лучше знает, в отличие от этого самого участника.

Серж, я все же добавлю один ответ, правда не очень огромный. // Я использую встроенную  в поисковик нейросеть
«Яндекс Нейро» — это сервис для поиска информации в интернете, разработанный «Яндексом». Он использует большую языковую модель YandexGPT 3 для генерации ответов на основе актуальных данных из поисковой выдачи.  Умеет редактировать и пересказывать тексты, задавать уточняющие вопросы и т. д.

Sharon. Чудесно! Вы уже занимаетесь рекламой (замечу, что вас о ПО никто не спрашивал). Продолжайте выдавать ответы ИИ за свои. Кстати, про роды притяжательных местоимений "свой"/"своя" вам "сервис нейросеть" ничего не подготовила? Как жаль.

Это я разъясняю вам ваше словесное изобретение "сервис нейросеть".  Также я думаю, что в скором времени ИИ будет меня цитировать, а не я ИИ))  А вам я рекомендую оставить меня в покое, лучше РЯ подтяните.

@ Sharon Я не сомневаюсь вас!

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE

Морфологический разбор притяжательных местоимений его, её, их

По учебнику Литневская Е. Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс для школьников, стр. 59
Также Грамота
Схема разбора
 1. Местоимение. Начальная форма — его / её / их.
 2. Морфологические признаки:
 а) постоянные:
 — притяжательное,
 — неизменяемое,
 б) непостоянные: нет.
 3. Синтаксическая роль в предложении: 
 несогласованное определение (его 
 книга, ее тетрадь, их приезд).


Правильность разбора притяжательных местоимений его, ее, их у Литневской не вызывает сомнений, так как следует из Большого толкового словаря Кузнецова: значение рода или числа включено в ЛЕКСИЧЕСКОЕ значение местоимений. Поэтому это значение не указывается в признаках при разборе.

ЕГО [во]. I. местоим. сущ. к Он (1.О.) и Оно. II. в зн. местоим. прил. Принадлежащий ему. Е. семья. Е. вещи. Письмо на е. имя.
ЕЁ. I. местоим. сущ. к Она. II. в зн. местоим. прил. Принадлежащий ей. Её вещи. Её адрес. Её телефон. Её платье.
ИХ. 1. к Они. 2. в зн. местоим. прил. Принадлежащий им. Их мать. Их квартира. Их обязанность. Их увлечения. Их лица. На их месте.

О притяжательных местоимениях

Притяжательные прилагательные относятся к группе местоимений-прилагательных, так как отвечают на вопрос чей, как и прилагательные. Для сравнения:  (чей?) — мой.
Притяжательные местоимения его, ее, их являются неизменяемыми словами, и их не надо путать с падежными формами личных местоимений.
Притяжательные местоимения  его, ее, их указывают на принадлежность предмета третьему лицу мужского рода (его), женского рода (ее), или нескольким лицам (их).

Разбор личного местоимения ее для сравнения
1. Местоимение. Начальная форма — она (И.п. ед. 
число) 
2. Морфологические признаки:
а) постоянные признаки:
3-е лицо
б) Непостоянные признаки:
родительный падеж, единственное число, женский 
род.
3. Синтаксическая роль в предложении:  
дополнение.
Наконец он заметил (кого?) ее.




как бы правильнее задать вопрос… во всех источниках написано, что эти притяж.мест. не изменяются. то есть у них нет ни числа, ни рода? по падежам они не изменяются, это мне понятно. но моменты касаемо рода и числа мне непонятны

просто я думала, что они просто не склоняются по падежам. а вот по родам и числам склоняются. «его»- начальная форма, а «ее» и «их» это уже измененные формы. в морфологическом разборе мест. «ее,его,их» мы не будем указывать род и число?

Литневская - авторитетный учебник,  и вот она не указывает. У нее три слова, при этом каждое из них обозначает принадлежность определенному лицу/ лицам. То есть у нее  род и число входит  значение слов. Но нет уверенности в том, что все так разбирают. Морфология изучает формы слова, а здесь нет форм, так как слова неизменяемые (это уже точная характеристика этих слов). Поэтому указывается только разряд по значению. Мне понятен такой разбор, если только в  школе могут предложить другой. Например, указать род/число в пункте а)

он,она,оно,они тоже разные слова?

Нет, это формы слова он. которое изменяется по родам и числам, я как раз для этого привела разбор личного местоимения ее. Постоянный признак 3-е лицо, непостоянные род, число, падеж.  А вот начальные формы разные: он, она, они. А вообще трудная тема, многие путаются в ней. Хорошо, что у Литневской нашелся разбор притяжательных местоимений, а то такие фантазии пишут.

а его,ее,их уже будут отдельными местоимениями? у них уже если и определять род,то он будет поястоянный,правильно?

Да, это местоимения с постоянным значением рода или числа.

все же так странно, что они будут отдельными местоимениями…в моей голове они в этом похожи с личными местоимениями…

Считается, что притяжат. местоимения по происхождению связаны с личными местоимениями, но личные местоимения склоняются, а притяжательные нет. Уже эта разница не позволяет видеть их формой одного слова. Ну и значения разные: само лицо (предмет) и принадлежность лицу (признак предмета). Местоименное сущ. и местоименное прилагательное-определение, хотя и несогласованное

я имела в виду то,что «ее» не будет формой «его» это будут два разных местоимения,но почему? они ведь так похожи…

Тогда вся картинка сломается)  Они же неизменяемые, а получится, что изменяются по родам и числам.  Нелогично)
